# A difficulty in understanding the operation of a Turing machine on a certain language.

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, book-recommendation, turing-machines

The implementation-level description of Turing machines that decides the following language over the alphabet {a,b,c} is given below.

[image]
[image]
But I feel that the state diagram and the set of configurations will give me more subtlety in understanding, could anyone suggest a book for me that contains this? or could anyone explain it thoroughly for me?

Also, I could not see the difference between the above The implementation-level description of Turing machines and the one given below:

[image]

Why both implementations are right?

Thanks!

Comment: After one has worked out some simpler Turing machines at the "machine code" level, it starts to get tedious. The description could be a little more specific about what it means by phrases such as "shuttle between the b's and c's," but do you really need the state-transition rules for "return the head to the left-hand end of the tape" or "restore the crossed-off b's"? Note that you always have the option to try to write the rules yourself.

Comment: I do not have this boldness @DavidK ..... I have edited my question could u see it please if you have time?

Comment: I only see one difference between the two implementations: one requires 1 or more of each symbol ($a^+b^+c^+$), the other only asks for 0 or more of each symbol ($a^*b^*c^*$). In the 0 or more case, it seems to me the implementation should say what happens if there are no a's to cross off the first time step 3 occurs. (I think it should reject.)